# UITableView - get existing viewForHeaderInHeaders

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to get the existing header views in a UITableView, so that I can update their appearances. I have been unable to find a method similar to visibleCells that would return the header views instead of cells. Is this possible, or should I just store these views during creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store them in an NSMutableArray. Here is some sample code:

```
@interface ViewController : UITableViewController (UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate)
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *sectionHeaderViews;
@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  self.sectionHeaderViews = [NSMutableArray array];
  NSInteger numOfSections = [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:self.tableView];
  for(int i=0; i<numOfSections)
  {
     CustomHeaderView *headerView = [[CustomHeaderView alloc] init];

     // customize headerView here
     ...

     [self.sectionHeaderViews addObject:headerView];
  }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [self.sectionHeaderViews objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (void)updateViewForSection:(NSInteger)section {
  CustomHeaderView *headerView = [self.sectionHeaderViews objectAtIndex:section];

  // update headerView here
  ...

  // reload section
  [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:section] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}

@end
```

Good luck!

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I see why they introduced UITableViewHeaderFooterView. Thanks!

Comment: The good thing with UITableViewHeaderFooterView is that you could deque them for reuse just like you do with regular cells, but of course this needs your minimum deploy target to be iOS 6.0 and above.

Comment: BTW I also use the Sensible TableView framework, where each section already has a property called 'headerView' that you could modify at anytime. Also worth taking a look at for many other features that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
[tableView headerViewForSection:sectionNum];
```

Comment: I'm using pre-6.0 headers, not UITableViewHeaderFooterView.

Comment: In that case, you probably should just store your views by section in an NSArray.